# Activating PAM configuration for Percona

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, pam, ubuntu-16.04, percona

I'm trying to configure Percona with LDAP support via PAM including group mappings and restriction.  My Percona authentication setup is as follows:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN pam SONAME 'auth_pam.so';

create user 'dba'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_pam AS 'mysql';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'dba'@'%' with grant option;

create user 'dbr'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_pam AS 'mysql';
grant select on *.* to 'dbr'@'%';

CREATE USER ''@'' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_pam AS 'mysql, sudo=dba, mysql=dbr';
GRANT PROXY ON 'dba'@'%' TO ''@'';
GRANT PROXY ON 'dbr'@'%' TO ''@'';
```

And in /etc/pam.d/mysql I have:

```
auth required pam_warn.so
auth required pam_ldap.so
account required pam_ldap.so
account required pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup mysql
```

With these in place, the following works:

- Log in as an LDAP user in sudo (and mysql), gain privileges of dba.
- Log in as an LDAP user in mysql, gain privileges of dbr.
- Attempt login with invalid username and/or password, get no access.

And the following behaviors are incorrect (should be refused login entirely):

- Log in as an LDAP user in sudo (but not mysql), still gain privileges of dba.
- Log in as an LDAP user in neither group, gain access with no privileges.

It took quite a while to eventually figure out that the configuration in `/etc/pam.d/mysql` is having no effect.  The behavior is the same even when that file is not present.

My understanding is that the first value in the string `mysql, sudo=dba, mysql=dbr` tells Percona to use the PAM configuration in a file named mysql, and all tutorials show the filename resolving to `/etc/pam.d/mysql`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be moved over to http://dba.stackexchange.com?  However, the mysql/percona-related portion of this setup seems pretty straightforward and I suspect the problem is rooted in PAM itself, not the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be file permissions.  When `/etc/pam.d/mysql` was changed from `0640` to `0644` (o+r), the PAM configuration started affecting login as expected.